# Efficient MySQL SELECT last occurence <= date, IF this last occurence matches an additional condition

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

I have a MySQL `dev_table` with thousands of products identified by their Name, containing changes to price and availability (among other values) over time. The table contains only the dates where a change occurred.

I am looking for an efficient way to select the latest results for all products available on a certain date – e.g. on 2016-01-01 – even though there may be no entry for the product for the given date.

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));

CREATE TABLE `dev_table` (`uid` int(11) NOT NULL, `Name` varchar(200) NOT NULL, `Date` date NOT NULL, `Available` tinyint(1) NOT NULL, `Price` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL, `Size` tinyint(1) NOT NULL); 

ALTER TABLE `dev_table` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`uid`);

INSERT INTO `dev_table` (`uid`, `Name`, `Date`, `Available`, `Price`, `Size`) VALUES
(1, 'product A', '2000-01-01', 1, '123.33', 5), (2, 'product B', '2000-01-01', 1, '17.50', 1), (3, 'product C', '2003-06-01', 1, '578.25', 6), (4, 'product A', '2015-08-07', 1, '131.67', 2), (5, 'product D', '2016-01-01', 1, '8.02', 2),
(6, 'product C', '2016-01-01', 0, '478.72', 6), (7, 'product A', '2023-01-27', 1, '134.07', 5), (8, 'product B', '2023-09-01', 0, '12.01', 1);
```

```
+-----+------------+-------------+-----------+--------+------+ 
| uid | Name       | Date        | Available | Price  | Size |
+-----+------------+-------------+-----------+--------+------+
|   1 | product A  | 2000-01-01  | 1         | 123.33 |    5 |
|   2 | product B  | 2000-01-01  | 1         |  17.50 |    1 |
|   3 | product C  | 2003-06-01  | 1         | 578.25 |    6 |
|   4 | product A  | 2015-08-07  | 1         | 131.67 |    2 |
|   5 | product D  | 2016-01-01  | 1         |   8.02 |    2 |
|   6 | product C  | 2016-01-01  | 0         | 478.72 |    6 |
|   7 | product A  | 2023-01-27  | 1         | 134.07 |    5 |
|   8 | product B  | 2023-09-01  | 0         |  12.01 |    1 |
+-----+------------+-------------+-----------+--------+------+
```

I use 2 nested subqueries to achieve this:

```
SELECT * FROM `dev_table`
WHERE `uid` IN (
    SELECT max(subquery1.`uid`) AS lastUid FROM `dev_table` AS subquery1
    WHERE subquery1.`Date` <= '2016-01-01' 
    AND subquery1.`Name` NOT IN (
        SELECT subquery2.`Name` FROM `dev_table` AS subquery2
        WHERE subquery2.`Date` <= '2016-01-01' 
        AND subquery2.`Available` != 1
    ) 
    GROUP BY subquery1.`Name`
    ORDER by lastUid DESC
);
```

This does return the rows for uid 2, 4 and 5 as expected, these being the latest entries for product B, A and D respectively, and not returning uid 6, as product D is not available on the given date.

This solution is inefficient on larger tables, however. It gets even worse when adding more criteria such as `` MATCH (`Name`) AGAINST ('product' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ``. Also, `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` does seem a bit outdated.

How can I improve this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current query suggests that a product cannot go from `Available = 0` back to `Available = 1`. Is this correct? If not, both your query and SelVazi's will return incorrect results, as they will not include products which become available again.

Assuming products can become available again, you need to check the availability of the most recent row on, or before, the desired date. Whether a window function (as suggested by Amit) or max subquery is more efficient will depend on the scale and distribution of your data, as well as the rest of the query.

This query requires that both `uid` and `Date` are in sequence, but should be slightly more efficient as it joins on PK, not a secondary index:

```sql
SELECT `dt`.*
FROM (
    SELECT MAX(`uid`) AS `max_uid`
    FROM `dev_table`
    WHERE `Date` <= '2016-01-01'
    GROUP BY `Name`
) AS `most_recent`
JOIN `dev_table` AS `dt`
    ON `most_recent`.`max_uid` = `dt`.`uid`
WHERE `dt`.`available` = 1;
```

This query joins on the secondary index, so may be slightly less efficient than the query above, and it will produce multiple rows for the same `Name` if there are multiple rows for the same `Name` on the same `Date` (e.g. different sizes):

```sql
SELECT `dt`.*
FROM (
    SELECT `Name`, MAX(`Date`) AS `max_date`
    FROM `dev_table`
    WHERE `Date` <= '2016-01-01'
    GROUP BY `Name`
) AS `most_recent`
JOIN `dev_table` AS `dt`
    ON `most_recent`. `Name` = `dt`.`Name`
    AND `most_recent`.`max_date` = `dt`.`Date`
WHERE `dt`.`available` = 1;
```

Both of these queries require an index on `(Name, Date)`:

```sql
ALTER TABLE `dev_table` ADD INDEX `idx_name_date` (`Name`, `Date`);
```

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/bQ7JjsvU).

Comment: A very valid point. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `HAVING` clause to exclude those with at least one unavailable flag, to do so, we must select only those with total available products. Total products '`SUM(d.Available)`' equal total products '`COUNT(*)`' :

```
SELECT d.Name, max(d.uid) AS lastUid
FROM dev_table AS d
WHERE d.`Date` <= '2016-01-01'
GROUP BY d.Name
HAVING SUM(d.Available) = COUNT(*);
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/e1YgbL8f)

Comment: You can use `HAVING MIN(d.Available) = 1`, instead of calculating both aggregates. Probably not a massive difference in this case, but worth bearing in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You're right that nested subqueries can become quite inefficient, especially as the table grows. One approach to optimize your query is by using window functions and common table expressions (CTEs).

```
WITH LatestProductInfo AS (
    SELECT uid, Name, Date, Available, Price, Size,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Date DESC, uid DESC) AS rn
      FROM dev_table
     WHERE Date <= '2016-01-01'
)
SELECT uid, Name, Date, Available, Price, Size
  FROM LatestProductInfo
WHERE rn = 1
  AND (Available = 1);
```